# How to use kyotocabinet(JNI) in playframework?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, playframework, kyotocabinet

I'm tackling to use kyotocabinet in Playframework.
and following error occurred.

I'm using Eclipse and playframework-1.2.3.
and kyotocabinet is native library so I'm using its Java-Binding.

the reproduce code is simple.
in controller:

```
public static void somePage() {
    DB db = new DB();//error occurred
    render();
}

Internal Server Error (500) for request GET /
Execution exception (In /app/controllers/TestApp.java around line 45)
NoClassDefFoundError occured : Could not initialize class kyotocabinet.DB

play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException: Could not initialize class kyotocabinet.DB
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:229)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class kyotocabinet.DB
    at controllers.TestApp.somePage(TestApp.java:45)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:546)

    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:500)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:476)

    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:471)

    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:159)
    ... 1 more
```

build in Eclipse was completed but error occured at runtime.

I guess it is because kyotocabinet.dll is missing.(only jkyotocabinet.jar was found)
I configured the location of kyotocabinet.dll to Java Build Path > Source > Native Library Location of my playframework project.
and it was good in other projects.

How to use native library in playframework?
any example or tutorial?

Play.getFile and System.load didn't work.

```
package controllers;
import play.Play;
import play.jobs.*;

@OnApplicationStart
public class Bootstrap extends Job {
public void doJob() {
    String path = "D:/MyProject/lib/jkyotocabinet.dll";
    Play.getFile(path);
    //System.load(path); if this was enabled, following error occurred: "Native Library D:\MyProject\lib\jkyotocabinet.dll already loaded in another classloader". so I guess the dll was loaded.
    System.out.println("bootstrap loaded");//this is displayed.
}
}

UnsatisfiedLinkError occured : no jkyotocabinet in java.library.path
```

this Japanese blog tells Play!Framework cannot load native library.
http://d.hatena.ne.jp/hjym_u/20110702/1309609277

I already tried these: Absolute path, Relative path, System.load, System.loadLibrary, Play.getFile.

as conclusive approach, I put jkyotocabinet.dll to current directory(D:/MyProejct/), and wrote this code.

```
public static void somePage(){
    File f = Play.getFile("jkyotocabinet.dll");
        if(f != null && f.isFile() && f.canRead() && f.canExecute()){//true
            DB db = new DB();//error occured. it reached here.
        }
    render();
}

Execution exception
NoClassDefFoundError occured : Could not initialize class kyotocabinet.DB
```

Play.getFile found the path "jkyotocabinet.dll" so jkyotocabinet.dll is in current directory so jvm should find it automatically.

anyone can use JNI in playframework?

finally, I could use kyotocabinet as PROD mode but not DEV mode.

Project/conf/application.conf

```
#application.mode=dev
application.mode=prod
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you just need to load the dll into Java via [System.load](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#load%28java.lang.String%29)

If you place the ddl on your project, you may load it via [Play.getFile](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/Play.java#L774) inside your @OnApplicationStart controller. This should make it available to your application while the JVM is alive.

EDIT:

@KenichiYamamoto Play.getFile gets files from the application path. You are trying to use a full path in there.

[Read this](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#I.27m_encountering_classloader_problems_when_using_JNI_under_Tomcat) about loading the file in a container. It may be that (due to Play compile-reload system) you are hitting the "already loaded" error. Try to follow the example by adding the System.load inside a static block in your @OnApplicationStart

Answer (score 0):

Do as pere says but use the relative path from your application root. Not the absolute path. I.e. Play.getFile("lib\myfile.dll")